# Use of undeclaring type 'T'

Tags: generics, swift, types

Good morning, i have this class DownloadQueue based on
[this tutorial](http://waynewbishop.com/swift/stacks-queues/)

the code :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftHTTP

    public class DownloadQueue<T> {


    var request: HTTPTask;

    private var top: QNode<T>!

    init(){
        self.request = HTTPTask();
        self.top = QNode<T>();
    }


    func enQueue(var key: T) { //check for the instance
        if (top == nil) {
            top = QNode()
        } //establish the top node

        if (top.key == nil) {
            top.key = key;
            return
        }
        var childToUse: QNode<T> = QNode<T>()
        var current: QNode = top //cycle through the list of items to get to the end.

        while (current.next != nil) {
            current = current.next!
        } //append a new item

        childToUse.key = key;
        current.next = childToUse;
    }

    func deQueue() -> T? { //determine if the key or instance exists
        let topitem: T? = self.top?.key
        if (topitem == nil) {
            return nil
        }
        //retrieve and queue the next item
        var queueitem: T? = top.key! //use optional binding
        if let nextitem = top.next
        {
            top = nextitem
        } else {
            top = nil
        }
        return queueitem
    }

    func isEmpty() -> Bool {
        //determine if the key or instance exist
        if let topitem: T = self.top?.key
        {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }

    func addDownload(url: NSString){
        enQueue(url as T);
        while (!isEmpty()){
            var item: T? = deQueue();
            println(item as NSString);
        }
    }



}
```

Class QNode

```
import Foundation
class  QNode<T> {
    var key: T? = nil
    var next: QNode? = nil
}
```

The problem is coming when i try to istantiate this class from another class infact writing this line from another class:

```
var queue: DownloadQueue<T> = DownloadQueue<T>() ;
```

generate error

Use of undeclared type T;

I don't now why and i'm going crazy. Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T` is a placeholder for a concrete type that you have to specify when you instantiate your generic class, so for example, if `DownloadQueue` has to deal with an `Int` type, you have to instantiate it as:

```
var queue = DownloadQueue<Int>()
```

Suggested reading: [Generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-XID_275)